# To block particular css content in some specific pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, django-templates

I have css properties on html, though i want to block this particular css property on specific pages.

> ```
>     html {
>         -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); 
>         zoom: 0.8; 
>         zoom: 80%; 
>         overflow-x: hidden;
>     }
> ```

Now this I have done in base file and I cannot exclude base.html , how can I block this css on any other page?

P.S: I am using block html(django template), therefore  tag is only present in the base.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach this css on a class?

like:

```
html.className {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); 
    zoom: 0.8; 
    zoom: 80%; 
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and then on the page you want to use it add

```
<html class="className">
```

or different approach

```
html:not(.className) {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); 
    zoom: 0.8; 
    zoom: 80%; 
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

this will set it to all pages who doesnt have that class, so on page where you dont want to use this css just add:

```
<html class="className">
```

Another solution is to put this css as style element to head of your page where you want to use it but thats not so smart.

Comment: This is definitely a approach but I am not using native html, I am using block html, so the <html> tag is only present in base.html , so whereever base.html in included <html> tag is not added.

Comment: oh, and why you dont use that css on body instead of html?

Comment: Its kind of necessary, due to other elements such as tooltip positioning, popover etc.

Comment: well then only thing that gets on my mind is to use javascript... on that page you dont want to just append a class to your html tag and still use that :not(yourClass) and it will do...